# how to debug backchannel

Tags: c#, botframework, ngrok, direct-line-botframework

I am following this Hand-off sample: https://github.com/ankitbko/human-handoff-bot

I want to debug through the code and see how the Agent's "Connect" button works - to see how it adds Agents into the Pool (because I always get the message `All our customer care representatives are busy at the moment. Please try after some time.`).

I have the ngrok set-up as instructed:
`using command ngrok.exe http --host-header=rewrite <port number>`

I have the Agent UI working, I see from the UI that I am connected, but I never enter my code breakpoints. And when I tried updating the messages, I see that it always shows what I published, and not what I have locally. I assume I always get connected to the published bot instead of what I have running locally... how do I debug the local Agent code?

Comment: Have you changed the messaging endpoint for the bot registration?  https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: @EricDahlvang that's exactly what I was missing. I will mark it as answer if you will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the messaging endpoint for the bot registration?

This blog post might be helpful: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/